# Why does using cluster= argument in mgcv::bam() result in an error?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, gam, mgcv

I am trying to reproduce the example given in here:

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/mgcv/html/mgcv-parallel.html

Specifically, the use of the cluster= argument in mgcv::bam().

Reproducible example:

```
require(mgcv)
require(parallel) 

    k <- 13;bs <- "cr"; set.seed(9)
    dat <- gamSim(1,n=6000,dist="poisson",scale=.1)

    nc <- 2   ## cluster size, set for example portability
    if (detectCores()>1) { ## no point otherwise
      cl <- makeCluster(nc) 
    } else cl <- NULL

    system.time(b3 <- bam(y ~ s(x0,bs=bs,k=7)+s(x1,bs=bs,k=7)+s(x2,bs=bs,k=k)
                ,data=dat,family=poisson(),chunk.size=5000,cluster=cl))
```

This results in the following error on my machine:

> Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) :    2 nodes produced errors; first
>   error: no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of
>   class "gam" Timing stopped at: 0.31 0 0.37

Other information which may be of use:

```
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
```

My machine has 4 cores and 16 GB RAM.

Thank you.

Comment: I could not reproduce the error with `parallel 3.5.1` and `mgcv 1.8.27` and `R 3.5.1` and I get a proper result. Maybe updating the packages may help?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't reproduce the error & got this output.

```
> b3

Family: poisson 
Link function: log 

Formula:
y ~ s(x0, bs = bs, k = 7) + s(x1, bs = bs, k = 7) + s(x2, bs = bs, 
    k = k)

Estimated degrees of freedom:
3.64 4.05 9.95  total = 18.64 

fREML score: 8563.705
```

Try updating the packages and see if that helps. Otherwise some more insight would be useful.

Comment: Thankyou and also @thothal for the idea of updating packages. I updated mgcv but this disnt seem to help. I think I need to update my version of R (currently 3.4.4) in order to update the parallel library as this is a core package. Whilst waiting for my IT department to update R on my machine (since I dont have administrative privalages) I ran the code using Louis Aslett's RStudio AMI through an Amazon EC2 instance and it worked fine with no errors. So there is surely something wrong with my R installation. Will update when R version is updated!

Comment: Seems that updating R to the newest version has helped as I no longer get the error message. Still a bit of a mystery to me as to why that specific error message. Im not sure this question is "answered" so perhaps leave it be for the time being in case anybody else encounters this issue?